# How to get posts' content as HTML from a wordpress blog remotely

Tags: wordpress, rss, xml-rpc

I have a self-hosted WordPress blog, and I am making a static home page for my website based on jQuery.
So, I wanted to display some content from my blog, on my home page (in widgets), as a news section.

For example, I may fetch

- the latest five posts' titles and content
- OR a specific page content (via passing the page id)
- OR a specific post (via passing the post id)

So does WordPress include any PHP file that shows the posts contents as plain text, or HTML?

I thought about fetching the blog's RSS, and then show it on the page, but the RSS doesn't provide the full content of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's hosted on the same server, you could [integrate WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) into your app by including `wp-blog-header.php`, and then call [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts), using `setup_postdata()`.

For example:

```
 <ul>
     <?php
         global $post;
         $tmp_post = $post;
         $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5&offset=1&category=1');
         foreach($myposts as $post) :
             setup_postdata($post);
     ?>

         <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

         <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>
 </ul>
```

Comment: yes, it is hosted on the same server , but not the same sub-domain.  
  
the blog is hosted at blog.mydomain.com  
and the homepage will be at www.mydomain.com .

Can I still include WordPress's header ??
if yes, what about if I wanted to get a static-page content ?

Comment: I just got an idea , I can add a php file to my Wordpress 
which takes the post/page id as a GET parameter , and just echo the content
later I call this php page from my Homepage via AJAX

Comment: As long as the two sites are running on the same physical machine, they could have different subdomains, different domains, or even different IP addresses sometimes. The important fact is that they're on the same machine. If that's the case, you can just include the wordpress header, just like any PHP file on the same machine.

Comment: There's definitely no need for the overhead of XML-RPC if you're on the same machine.

Comment: And definitely not the *double* overhead of Yahoo! Pipes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/).