# How can RWordPress retrieve blog post content?

Tags: r, xml, wordpress

I would like to retrieve the content of posts from my WordPress blog.  Using the package `RWordPress` it is straightforward to retrieve categories and tags and titles, but what about the content of posts?

```
# Download and load the package
if (!require('RWordPress')) {
    devtools::install_github(c("duncantl/XMLRPC", "duncantl/RWordPress"))
  }

library(RWordPress)

# list all the functions in the package
lsf.str("package:RWordPress")
```

Here, for example, is the code to obtain categories, with my specifics redacted in brackets:

```
Cat <- getCategoryList(login = c([my user name] = '[my password'),
        .server = 'http://[my blog on].wpengine.com/xmlrpc.php')
```

The linked SO question is not applicable as it doesn't use RWordPress [[HTML and CSS and PHP coding]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572027/how-to-get-posts-content-as-html-from-a-wordpress-blog-remotely).

This site is about posting on WordPress, not retrieving from WordPress [[publishing, not gettting]](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/wordpress/).  Another question uses xmlrpc as does RWordPress and a getPosts call, but it does not rely on R.

```
Posts <- getPosts(num = 100, blogid = 0L, login = c([my user name] = '[my password]'), .server = 'http://[my blog name].wpengine.com/xmlrpc.php')
```

The above code returns dates and titles and status, but not content.

Thank you for any guidance.

******************* Edit after first answer

After requiring `RWordPress` and `XMLRPC`, and then defining an object for login and for the .server, here is the console message:

```
> getPageList(blogid = 0L, login = WordpressLogin, .server = WordpressURL)
Error in xml.rpc(.server, op, as.integer(blogid), names(login), as.character(login),  : 
  Problems
```

I find that "Problems" is not an informative error message for me.

Comment: Edit: Reposting comment here so it will be closer to your edit-- Generally it returns some fault code. I get this particular 'problem'error only when the `url of xmlrpc.php file` on the server is wrong.  Suggest you check it by directly entering in browser. BTW, I later ran the code to fetch posts from a remote server  and it still worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell me if I am missing something, but for me the `description` identifier of posts seem to deliver the whole text.

RWordpress maps all the functions in [XML-RPC wp](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp)

```r
if (!require('RWordPress')) {
  devtools::install_github(c("duncantl/XMLRPC", "duncantl/RWordPress"))
}
library(RWordPress)
options(WordpressLogin = c(myusername = 'mypassword'),
        WordpressURL = 'http://localhost/myblog/wordpress/xmlrpc.php')
# library(knitr)

# can refer this page
# http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp

#Rwordpress has a one to one mapping 
getCategories()

#get a list of pages
getPageList()
# pick one id from above list 
id=27
getPage(pageid = id)
# description seems to have all the text of post, even though the 
# document is sparse
getPage(pageid = id)$description

#similarly for posts
getPost(postid = 6)$description
```

I am of course using a locally installed blog, but I'd reckon this should work remotely.

Comment: Much obliged, R.S., but see my edits to my question.

Comment: Generally it returns some fault code. I get this particular 'problem'error only when the `url of xmlrpc.php file` on the server is wrong.  Suggest you check it by directly entering in browser. BTW, I later ran the code to fetch posts from a remote server  and it still worked fine.

Comment: I checked the URL code and got this message: "XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only."  I am using WPEngine.com as my host.  Perhaps it blocks what other servers allow?

Comment: That means the xmlrpc.php is present right there and working. There may be some other server config issue if the parameters are   correctly set. I think you should contact the host to check if there are restrictions on XMLRPC engine.

Comment: Indeed, my host blocks it.   I will accept your answer since you have devoted much time to helping me.

Comment: Oh. That puts paid to RWordpress option, then.  I  think you can just as  simply scrape the blog using `rvest`. Thanks for accepting the answer, though the little research I put in helped me as well (if only to make me wary of XMLRPC :-) ) . Thanks.